# Is there a way to transform String to Map<dynamic, dynamic> in Flutter

Tags: json, string, flutter, dynamic

Is there a way to transform String to Map<dynamic, dynamic> in Flutter?

```
String myString = "mytexthere";

Map<dynamic, dynamic> fieldData = jsonDecode(myString);
Map<dynamic, dynamic> fieldData = new Map<dynamic, dynamic>.from(myString);
Map<dynamic, dynamic> fieldData = myString.cast<dynamic, dynamic>();
Map<dynamic, dynamic> fieldData = Map<dynamic, dynamic>.from(myString);
```

It seems that none of the above work? Is there a correct way to do this?

EDIT 3:
Here is what worked:

```
Map<dynamic, dynamic> fieldData = {"body": myString};
```

Comment: What would be the expected output? A map consists of multiple entries of key:value. Should string be a key a value or both? How many entries would the map have ?

Comment: @ValdaXD - please check my edit, I'm trying to build a list of draggable notes and the data should be of this type Map<dynamic, dynamic>

Comment: Draggable data doesn't have to be a map, unless you need it to be a map. Since apparently you don't have much idea of how a map works, I don't think you need it. Then just change Draggable <Map>, for Draggable<String>. Same here Map<dynamic, dynamic> fieldData

Comment: But if you want to use a string on a map, it's simple, a map is composed of key: value, then just do Map <dynamic, dynamic> fieldData = {"myKey": jsonDecode (documentSnapshot ["body"])}; and you access with fieldData ["myKey"]

Comment: That worked, but I just realized it won't fix my actually problem in EDIT 2. However if you post it as an answer I will accept it.